# Play Framework Cross Domain Web Service

Tags: json, web-services, rest, playframework, jsonp

I've been trying to create a Web Service with play framework. I've searched some tutorial and resource about this and end up using the **renderJSON()** method to provide JSON RESTful web service.

But, there seems to be a problem with that when I try to consume the web service with JQuery. If I use **JSON**, it fails with this error `Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Which seems to be a cross-domain problem. Then I try to use **JSONP** as the datatype when JQuery trying to consume the web service, again there's an parseError problem.

After some research, I found that to provide a web service to the JSONP request. We need to provide something like a callback function. So it's not enough to return only the JSON object to the client. If I'm not mistaken, The format should look something like ***{#callback-function}{#JSON-data}***

How to make a Cross-Domain web service in Play Framework? Is there any workaround for this?
Is there anyway to keep the JSON format of a/a list of object to a string instead of render the object as JSON directly as done by calling **renderJSON()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did. In my routes I set the format of the response to javascript with:

GET   /api/projects.json     Api.projects(format:'json')

Then for the controller in Api I used [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) and did this:

```
public static void projects(String p) {
        JSONSerializer json = new JSONSerializer();
        List<Project> projects = Project.all().fetch(3);
        renderJSON(p + '(' + json.serialize(projects) + ')');
    }
```

So now jsonp calls can be made by hitting /api/projects.json?p=whatever and the return will be:

```
whatever([{"your":"json"}])
```

You can also use flexjson to only serialize the parts of the object that you want to expose.

Testing it with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api/projects.json",
  dataType: "jsonp", 
  jsonp : 'p',
  crossDomain : true,
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of doing the p/brackets thing yourself, use ```play.libs.Jsonp.jsonp```.

Answer (score 0):

This is working great but you can use Gson object directly instead of the flexjson object.